# I'm trying to configure memcache module and failed to load dmemcache.inc

Tags: caching

Anybody could have an Idea why I get this error
    Failed to load required file sites/all/modules/memcache/dmemcache.inc.

I installed memcache properly on my server, but when I go to drupal Report, I got the above message

I'm using drupal 7

```
This is from my PHPInfo()
memcached
memcached support   enabled
Version     2.1.0
libmemcached version    1.0.8
Session support     yes
igbinary support    no
json support    no

Directive   Local Value Master Value
memcached.compression_factor    1.3 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold 2000    2000
memcached.compression_type  fastlz  fastlz
memcached.serializer    php php
memcached.sess_binary   0   0
memcached.sess_lock_wait    150000  150000
memcached.sess_locking  1   1
memcached.sess_prefix   memc.sess.key.
```

**** UPDATE ****
in order to make it work, I added that to the settings file

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
  $conf['lock_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache-lock.inc';
  $conf['memcache_stampede_protection'] = TRUE;
  $conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';

  // The 'cache_form' bin must be assigned to non-volatile storage.
  $conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';

  // Don't bootstrap the database when serving pages from the cache.
  $conf['page_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;
  $conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modifications to settings.php are required. Read the docs on how to configure it. Here is an example configuration I use with two memcached servers:

```
$conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = __FILE__;
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['lock_inc'] = 'sites/all/modules/contrib/memcache/memcache-lock.inc';
$conf['memcache_stampede_protection'] = TRUE;
$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
$conf['page_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;
$conf['memcache_servers'] = ['172.16.12.51:11211' => 'default', '172.16.12.52:11211' => 'default'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem with the `domain` module which required to include in *settings.php* line:

```php
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/domain/settings.inc';
```

As it is internally calling `drupal_bootstrap()` then every change of `$conf` after that line is ignored. Solution was to define `$conf` variables before the mentioned line.